# Springboot actuator return redis health down in redis cluster mode

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

I'm using springboot actuator to monitor the health of the application. And the application use redis with cluster mode.

When all nodes of redis up, the interface `actuator/health` return

`"redis":{"status":"UP","details":{"cluster_size":3,"slots_up":16384,"slots_fail":0}}`

It works fine.

The redis cluster has three master nodes and three slave nodes.When i shutdown one slave node,The cluster is available anyway.But `actuator/health` alternately returns

`"redis":{"status":"UP","details":{"cluster_size":3,"slots_up":16384,"slots_fail":0}}`

and

`"redis":{"status":"DOWN","details":{"error":"org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException: Redis command timed out; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: Command timed out after 6 second(s)"}}`

- SpringCloud version: 20.0.2
- Redis version: 6.2.2

The springboot configuration is

```
redis:
    cluster:
      nodes:
        - 127.0.0.1:6379
        - 127.0.0.1:6380
        - 127.0.0.2:6379
        - 127.0.0.2:6380
        - 127.0.0.3:6379
        - 127.0.0.3:6380
      max-redirects: 3
    password: XXXXXXXXX
    timeout: 6000
    lettuce:
      cluster:
        refresh:
          adaptive: true
          period: 100
```

Can the `actuator/health` returns up when the cluster is available but one slave down?

Answer (score 1):

When communicating with a Redis cluster, Spring Boot's health indicator uses the [`CLUSTER INFO` command](https://redis.io/commands/cluster-info) to determine Redis's health. This command is failing due to a timeout so Spring Boot cannot determine the cluster's health and assumes that it is down.

You may be able to avoid the problem by increasing the timeout period. It can be configured using `spring.redis.timeout` which you've currently set to 6 seconds (6000ms).

Comment: The node is shutdown by myself but the cluster  is available anyway,why actuator return down? you mean the Spring Boot's health indicator connect to each node and use `CLUSTER INFO` to determine Redis's health?

Comment: Actuator returned down because the request for information about the cluster timed out. The health indicator calls `clusterGetClusterInfo()` on the `RedisClusterConnection` that's provided by Spring Data Redis. Exactly how this command is executed depends on the underlying implementation. You appear to be using Lettuce which executes the command on a randomly selected active node in the cluster.

Comment: Thanks,finally I know the reason why actuator return redis down.But is there anyway to avoid  actuator return redis down when just one node of the cluster down? is this case,the cluster is also available ,I think it should't be down

Comment: Actuator can't tell that only one node is down as its request for information about the cluster has timed out. If increasing the timeout does not address then I don't think there's anything that you or Actuator can do as I don't believe there's any other way for it to get the necessary information. Perhaps a change in how the active node is selected would help but I think that would require a change  in Spring Data Redis and/or Lettuce.